# How to update XML node using XML DML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I want to update a XML variable in SQL Server 2012.

Sample XML:

```
<ArrayOfFieldInfo>
    <FieldInfo>
        <Name>abc</Name>
        <FriendlyName>friend2</FriendlyName>
        <Description>Custom added field</Description>
        <FieldGroupName>Custom Fields</FieldGroupName>
    </FieldInfo>
    <FieldInfo>
        <Name>efg</Name>
        <FriendlyName>friend1</FriendlyName>
        <Description>Custom added field</Description>
        <FieldGroupName>Custom Fields</FieldGroupName>
    </FieldInfo>
</ArrayOfFieldInfo>
```

I want to update node `<FriendlyName>` with new value 'friend3' where `<Name>` node value is 'efg'.

I have tried following code but it doesn't work.

```
DECLARE @xmlTable table (xmlfield xml)

INSERT INTO @xmlTable (xmlfield) 
VALUES (
    '<ArrayOfFieldInfo>
        <FieldInfo>
            <Name>abc</Name>
            <FriendlyName>friend2</FriendlyName>
            <Description>Custom added field</Description>
            <FieldGroupName>Custom Fields</FieldGroupName>
        </FieldInfo>
        <FieldInfo>
            <Name>efg</Name>
            <FriendlyName>friend1</FriendlyName>
            <Description>Custom added field</Description>
            <FieldGroupName>Custom Fields</FieldGroupName>
        </FieldInfo>
    </ArrayOfFieldInfo>'
)


UPDATE @xmlTable
SET xmlfield.modify('replace value of (/ArrayOfFieldInfo/FieldInfo/FriendlyName/text())[1] with "friend3"')
WHERE xmlfield.value('(/ArrayOfFieldInfo/FieldInfo/Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') = 'efg'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you must add the filter as a predicate:

Your *mockup*. I added an ID column and three cases

1. One "efg"
2. No "efg"
3. Multiple occurances of "efg"

--Check it out

```
DECLARE @xmlTable table (ID INT IDENTITY, xmlfield xml)

INSERT INTO @xmlTable (xmlfield) 
VALUES (
    '<ArrayOfFieldInfo>
        <FieldInfo>
            <Name>abc</Name>
            <FriendlyName>friend2</FriendlyName>
        </FieldInfo>
        <FieldInfo>
            <Name>efg</Name>
            <FriendlyName>friend1</FriendlyName>
        </FieldInfo>
    </ArrayOfFieldInfo>'
)
,(
    '<ArrayOfFieldInfo>
        <FieldInfo>
            <Name>abc</Name>
            <FriendlyName>friend2</FriendlyName>
        </FieldInfo>
        <FieldInfo>
            <Name>xyz</Name>
            <FriendlyName>friend1</FriendlyName>
        </FieldInfo>
    </ArrayOfFieldInfo>'
)
,(
    '<ArrayOfFieldInfo>
        <FieldInfo>
            <Name>efg</Name>
            <FriendlyName>friend2</FriendlyName>
        </FieldInfo>
        <FieldInfo>
            <Name>efg</Name>
            <FriendlyName>friend1</FriendlyName>
        </FieldInfo>
    </ArrayOfFieldInfo>'
)
```

--Let's use some variables to get this more generic

```
DECLARE @SearchName NVARCHAR(100)=N'efg';
DECLARE @ReplaceWith NVARCHAR(100)=N'ABCDEFG';
```

--The query

```
UPDATE @xmlTable
SET xmlfield.modify('replace value of 
                     (/ArrayOfFieldInfo
                      /FieldInfo[Name=sql:variable("@SearchName")]
                      /FriendlyName/text())[1] 
                     with sql:variable("@ReplaceWith")')
WHERE xmlfield.exist('/ArrayOfFieldInfo
                      /FieldInfo[Name=sql:variable("@SearchName")]')=1;
```

--Check the result

```
SELECT * 
FROM @xmlTable t
ORDER BY t.ID;
```

The first case will get the value replaced.
No replacements in the second case.
Just ONE (the first) occurance in the third case is replaced.

The idea in short:

The XML-DML-method `replace value of` needs a singleton. You tried to filter with a `WHERE` externally, but you must tell the engine **which node *within* the XML** you want to address. It is the `<FieldInfo>`, where the interal `<Name>` equals your search phrase. Below this `<FieldInfo>` we pick the `<FriendlyName>` and replace the first one we've found.

I added a `WHERE` using `.exist()`. This will/can speed up the process as it will reduce the `.modify()` to rows, which have at least one fitting target element.

And you can see, that `.modify()` is limited to just one change per call. This can be very annoying... A workaround might be to shred and recreate the XML or to use XQuery-FLWOR.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from me.

Comment: Hi Shnugo if my xml value like   
<FieldInfo>
            <Name>efg</Name>
            <FriendlyName />
 </FieldInfo>
How can i update FriendlyName

Comment: @tfs wow, about three years later . However, I do not get your problem... There is *absolutely no difference* between `<name/>` and `<name></name>`. The `text()`-node is *below* the element, hence *within*. What do you want to achieve?